# Dropdown default and empty values for Kendo Angular UI

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

This HTML for the Kendo Angular dropdown leaves a single comma for the empty/default value and does not allow me to go back to an empty value once I've selected a value. I've played with all sorts of ternary operators on my template to no avail. Should I make a pipe for all instances of **LastName, FirstName** to make things easier?

```
 <kendo-dropdownlist id="cost-engineer-dropdown"
    formControlName="CostEngineerId"
    [defaultItem]="{ text: 'Select an Engineer', value: '' }"
    [data]="costEngineer | async"
    [textField]="'LastName'"
    [valueField]="'Id'"
    value="this.LastName"
    (valueChange)="valueChange('this.Id')"
    (selectionChange)="selectionChange($event)"
    [formControl]="masterProjectFormGroup.get('CostEngineerId')"
    [valuePrimitive]="true"
    [(ngModel)]="CostEngineerId"
    >
<ng-template kendoDropDownListItemTemplate let-dataItem>
    {{dataItem?.LastName}}, {{dataItem?.FirstName}}
</ng-template>
<ng-template kendoDropDownListValueTemplate let-dataItem>
    {{dataItem?.LastName}}, {{dataItem?.FirstName}}
</ng-template>
</kendo-dropdownlist>
```

Comment: The [documentation](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/dropdownlist/default-item/) states that the `defaultItem` has to match the data type of the data-elements. I've prepared a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/nFneVvUMYEzLIE1vzAAH?p=preview) to show a sample.

Comment: That was it. Thank you Philipp!